# Reusable object nested in Angular method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got a simple list, and I would like to make my code work without having to update three time the `admin2` object (I would like to use `admin2` just once, I need `admin2` to be equal to (property) `Admin2Component.admin2: IAdmin2`:

In other word I need to update this admin2 with the different pagination projectPagination: IPaginationResponse, consultantPagination: IPaginationResponse, newsletterPagination: IPaginationResponse

```
private updateList(
    projectPagination: IPaginationResponse <IProject>,
    consultantPagination: IPaginationResponse <IConsultant>,
    newsletterPagination: IPaginationResponse <INewsletter>
) {
    this.admin2 = projectPagination.data;
    this.pagination.total = projectPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination.page = projectPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;

    this.admin2 = consultantPagination.data;
    this.pagination.total = consultantPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination.page = consultantPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;

    this.admin2 = newsletterPagination.data;
    this.pagination.total = newsletterPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination.page = newsletterPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;
}
```

And later:

```
$onInit() {
    console.log(this.projectPagination, this.consultantPagination,
    this.newsletterPagination);
    this.updateList(
        this.projectPagination,
        this.consultantPagination,
        this.newsletterPagination
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add more information, your question is vague. What is the expected output? What are you receiving instead? Why are you reassigning 3 times instead of just using the 3rd set of values and assign only once? We need more specifics in order to help.

Comment: @Lansana later in the code i'll add $onInit method as I updated my code

Comment: I need this admin2 to be equal to (property) Admin2Component.admin2: IAdmin2

Comment: Can you explain why you are updating the value 3 times, one after another? That doesn't make any sense to me. You will always be getting the value of the last update, so why not remove the first 2 and just update with the last set of values? The last set of values will always override the first 2. (not that this solves your problem, I am just confused why you're doing this).

Comment: I need to update this admin2 with the different pagination projectPagination: IPaginationResponse<IProject>, consultantPagination: IPaginationResponse<IConsultant>, newsletterPagination: IPaginationResponse<INewsletter>

Comment: `=` would assign a variable, not update it, basically completely replacing the previous data for that variable. define your "update"; what format are those variables in?

Comment: those variables are equal to array comming from promises

Comment: Emile, I still need to know why you are reassigning the values 3 times. You do `this.admin2 = ...`, `this.pagination.total = ...`, and `this.pagination.page = ...` 3 times. Why? The first 2 times will be overwritten by the 3rd time. That code makes no sense to me. Shouldn't you be creating 3 sets of variables and assign the 3 values to each set, respectively? Then you will get 3 different sets of pagination values that you can use in your template.

Comment: @Lansana yes something like dat, in fact each admin2(the 3) are returning values comming from three different components and I have to apply the methods to each...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you have 3 different sets of pagination values and you need to reference all 3 in your component. But what you are doing is reassigning one set of your class properties to all 3 values one after the other. This will not give you the desired result because your class properties will always equal the last assignment.

Create 2 more sets of class properties, so you should go from something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    admin2: any;
    pagination: any;

    // ...
}
```

To something like this (give them better names, I'm just following your naming convention):

```
class MyClass {
    admin: IProject;
    pagination: IPaginationResponse<IProject>;

    admin2: IConsultant;
    pagination2: IPaginationResponse<IConsultant>;

    admin3: INewsletter;
    pagination3: IPaginationResponse<INewsletter>;

    // ...
}
```

So that gives you 3 different sets of class properties, each representing a different pagination object for your components.

Now change your `updateList` function to assign all 3 sets of properties instead of reassigning one set of the properties 3 times:

```
private updateList(
    projectPagination: IPaginationResponse <IProject>,
    consultantPagination: IPaginationResponse <IConsultant>,
    newsletterPagination: IPaginationResponse <INewsletter>
) {
    this.admin = projectPagination.data;
    this.pagination.total = projectPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination.page = projectPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;

    this.admin2 = consultantPagination.data;
    this.pagination2.total = consultantPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination2.page = consultantPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;

    this.admin3 = newsletterPagination.data;
    this.pagination3.total = newsletterPagination.meta.pagination.total;
    this.pagination3.page = newsletterPagination.meta.pagination.current_page;
}
```

Make sure you instantiate your class properties first, or they will all be `undefined`, so doing something like `this.pagination.foo` will give you a "cannot access `foo` of undefined" error.